# Mistakes in css classes in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, visual-composer

I'm using Divi Builder for my wordpress site. I have also used Visual Composer, too. After I design my page in Divi Builder or Visual Composer, if I change any attribute of any item, when the page is rendered, the attributes I changed are written with double quotes (") in css class.

For example, when I divide a row as 2/3 + 1/3, first column class is:

```
et_pb_column et_pb_column_"2_3"  et_pb_column_2
```

and the second column class is:

```
et_pb_column et_pb_column_"1_3"  et_pb_column_3
```

But they should be

```
et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_3 et_pb_column_3
```

and

```
et_pb_column et_pb_column_2_3 et_pb_column_2
```

How could I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you asking here...?

Comment: I can't find a question in your post, can you clarify what you need help with, and I'll be able to try and assist you further

Comment: Thank both of you. I edited

Comment: I'm going to say this is purely down to visual-composer... I'm not familiar with that, and it's nothing to do with Wordpress itself.

Comment: I also tried using Divi Builder but the problem still remains. Only way I found is after designing, changing the code via backend editor as changing double quotes in shortcodes with one quote ('), like [name="value"] to [name='value'] after this, It works. But I cannot do this with Divi Builder

Comment: Use one instead of the number 1 and so on as a work around

Comment: @CarolMcKay They are created automatically after designing, changing them with one, two ... does not work.

Comment: @TarıkİNCE Changing it to `'` wouldn't solve your problem, as I don't believe `"` is valid in a class name anyways. Seconding it being a bug with Visual Composer.

Comment: @abluejelly Really I tried lots of times. Changing short codes generated by Visual Composer with backend mode, as changing " to ', definitely works for me. For Divi Builder, I have to do this manually from database through phpMyAdmin table values.

Comment: It still shouldn't be inserting `"` to begin with. Stuff like this... This is why I avoid frontend designer programs like the plague, and half of why I wrote my own asp.net renderers lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling all plugins then re-enabling Divi Builder solved the problem. Thus, problem was because of one of the plugins. After your problem solved, enable plugins one by one while you refresh your broken page until it is broken again. Then remove or edit your last breaking plugin.